# Can you stop playing an audio slate once you exit the slate screen?

Tags: starfield

Audio slates are often used as progression items in quests, but can also be found when you are exploring. When you pick one up, it opens a screen where you choose to play it or simply exit the screen.

What I haven't figured out is after you play it, and *exit the screen for it*, there doesn't appear to be a way to stop the audio slate from continuing.  You can stop it if you didn't leave the screen for the slate, but after that I can't find a way to. Is there another way to stop the slate from rambling on?

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure, but choosing a slate without audio comment or choosing a book or another readable info should stop the previous audio play.

Comment: @PeterCo somewhat annoying, but an option. I also discovered today that if you talk to an NPC it will stop the audio as well. Valid answers, but was hoping for a "press this button" kind of answer :/